# Ajax post request have more than 4 mb file

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing an MVC 4 application.I am sending ajax post request to a controller action.When the post data is more than 4MB the requist to action is failing.What is the solution for this?

Comment: What is the error? and what version of **IIS** are you using?

Comment: error is internal server error

Answer (score 2):

You need to change two configuration parameters (value is in KB)

**In Web.Config**

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="8192" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**In IIS**

Update your 'Maximum allowed content length' setting, as described here : http://ajaxuploader.com/large-file-upload-iis-asp-net.htm

Comment: Thanks @christofr. But the actual problem is the ajax data have more than 4 mb file then the controller action is not invoking.

Comment: Yep, the action will not be invoked if the file size is greater than the value you have specified in the maxRequestLength property.

Answer (score 2):

You could try extending the size of one of these properties..

```
<system.web> 
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="x" />


<system.webServer> 
  <security> 
    <requestFiltering> 
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="x" ></requestLimits>
```

Set, `x` to the size limit you want.  Read [`this post`](http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/archive/2009/09/24/from-iis6-maxrequestlength-to-iis7-maxallowedcontentlengthfile-specifying-maximum-file-upload-size.aspx) for help.

Comment: Thanks @christiandev. But the actual problem is the ajax data have more than 4 mb file then the controller action is not invoking.