# Ajax callback with FormData fails for large files

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, multipartform-data, form-data

I've a `input file` control where I can upload `any kind` of file.
So, I'm getting the file and `storing in a FormData` and making an `ajax call` to my controller.
It is working fine with Images and small .mp3 files.
But when I'm uploading .mp3 files more than 5MB, it is going to the error function

My code goes like this :

```
 document.getElementById('fileUploadControl').onchange = function () {

        var data = new FormData();
        var files = $("#fileUploadControl").get(0).files;

        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            data.append("UploadedImage" + i, files[i]);
        }

        var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
            url: '/Main/BroadcastFileUpload/',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: LoadImages,
            error: OnLogoFail
        });

        ajaxRequest.done(function (xhr, textStatus) {
        });
    };

 <input type="file" multiple id="fileUploadControl" style="width:0px;height:0px" />
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21456458/ajax-post-request-have-more-than-4-mb-file

Comment: This problem is most likely related to upload limits. You will have to provide some information about backend part of application. Most crucial information would be where is it hosted (self-host, IIS of some version), since this greatly affects default limits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah...I found the solution.Thanks to @artm

I've changed the `maxRequestLength` in web.config

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="2097151" />
```

Comment: Or use `app.use(express.bodyParser({limit: '50mb'}));` for node.js with express :)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for as I didn't realize it was a setting in ASP.Net. I was wondering why I could barely find anything about this limitation as I thought it was a limitation of XHR and was Googling the wrong thing until I came across this post.

Comment: You saved my time. Thankyou so much for the solution

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly because of the server side post limit. They have a default size just for security concerns. If you use Tomcat, you can configure the connector in server.xml to set the maxPostSize. Mostly the default is 2MB.

It applies for any server with ASP, JSP or PHP. May be the configuration file may vary.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById('fileUploadControl').onchange = function () {

```
    var data = new FormData();
    var files = $("#fileUploadControl").get(0).files;

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        data.append("UploadedImage" + i, files[i]);
    }

    var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
        url: '/Main/BroadcastFileUpload/',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: LoadImages,
        error: OnLogoFail
    });

    ajaxRequest.done(function (xhr, textStatus) {
    });
};
```